# IF Account ID doesnt exist then Delete

Tags: mysql, database

Basicly I have a list of account ids that are link to a character in a game stored in mysql, what i want to do is make a query that does, if the account id is not in this list then delete  it

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should also include the (parts of the) table definitions here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove characters that no longer have a user, you could use:

```
DELETE characters 
FROM characters 
LEFT JOIN users USING (user_id) 
WHERE users.user_id IS NULL
```